# Filestack API send file through using Postman

Tags: postman, filestack

I am trying to send a PDF file using Postman using the below URL. I have just hidden my key for security purposes.

https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&filename=test123.pdf

In the body section I have selected "form-data" in which I have set the Key value "file" and selected a file from the Value section. When I click on send I received a message "Nothing found to store - pass in data or a URL". I passed an image by using the raw option by passing the base64 code of the image. In response it returns the URL but it doesn't open PDF and says failed to load PDF document.

If anyone has any idea what I am missing here? If anyone has done this before do let me know.

I tried sending a base64 code of the PDF file to Filestack API and also by selecting a file through Postman.